# VS Code running from two locations

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm just wondering why when I run a code in Visual Studio Code, the terminal shows that it runs from two locations. An example is in the screenshot in imgur.

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to have attached any screenshot

Comment: @JanPokorný We have to search imgur

Comment: I don't see any image in your question.

Comment: I corrected image in question - it was insterted in wrong way.

Comment: what locations do you means ? `C:\Users\Admin` or `f:/Python Project/Mad Libs/` ? First is `"Current Working Directory"` , second is file's location.

Comment: Yes the two, so when I want to run the program, the first locations also runs and shows like errors. Is it normal and should I just let it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"C:\Users\admin" is the default location when you run VS code

And "f:....py" is the location of your python file.

When you run your code, exactly VS Code run " python /.../your_file.py", so it happenings like you see

Answer (score 0):

In the internal terminal of VS Code, it is in the root folder of the current project by default (so, please open this folder in VS Code), and when we click the run button, it will execute the run command in the terminal "python file_name.py", therefore, the terminal displays the path of the python executed file.

[image]

If the code cannot run the python file in the VS Code terminal, please try to reopen VS Code and open a new VS Code terminal.

Reference: [Getting Started with Python in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)